# wxWidgets Python save checkbox and other elements values in a text

Tags: python, checkbox, wxwidgets

How to save (and restore) the values of the graphical elements of the wxWidgets in Python?
I want some more friendly way, maybe using a `for` to scrape all the elements and save the current value in a `txt` when I close the window and restore when I load the app. I do not want to typing 2 line of code (save and restore) to each new element that I add.

Comment: what version of {wx}python do you use? what os/toolkit?

Comment: wxWidets = 4.0.0a3 gtk2 (phoenix), python 3 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: See http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_config_base.html for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Igor, thanks by the tip of use `config_base`. I created this code based on:

```
configHandle = wx.Config(CONFIG_FILE)
# Sweep all elements in `self()` to find the grafical ones
# instance of the wxPython and salve the specific configuration.
for wxElement_name, wxElement_handle in self.__dict__.items():
    # Each wxPython object have a specific parameter value
    # to be saved and restored in the software initialization.
    if isinstance(wxElement_handle, wx._core.TextCtrl):
        configHandle.Write(wxElement_name, wxElement_handle.GetValue() )
    elif isinstance(wxElement_handle, wx._core.CheckBox):
        configHandle.Write(wxElement_name, ('True' if wxElement_handle.GetValue() else 'False') )
    elif isinstance(wxElement_handle, wx._core.SpinCtrl):
        configHandle.Write(wxElement_name, str(wxElement_handle.GetValue()) )
    .
    .
    .
```

To restore I use the reverse logic of this code.